# Use 100% of edge to go between monitors

Tags: unity, compiz, multiple-monitors, mouse

My monitors are currently arranged like this:

```
        +---------+
        |         |
+------+|         |
|      ||         |
|      ||         |
+------++---------+
```

If I'm at the top-left corner of the right monitor, I can't move my mouse to the other screen - I need to move it down and around.

In ubuntu, preferably with compiz, is it possible to allow the mouse to use the whole edge for movement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

No, unless you change the alignment of your screens (System settings > "screens", drag the left screen up), but then you would have the same problem at the bottom.

In Unity (/Compiz), both screens together are seen as one big desktop/viewport. From that point of view, it would be undesirable behavior as well; the mouse would either make a weird jump down, or disappear to nowhere, and be invisible unless you move it down.

The first option would be inconsistent behavior in combination with possible windows, spread over two screens, the disadvantage of second option needs no further explanation I guess.

#### *However*

Like everything in computer life, it can be scripted, but again, I would not want that, for the reasons above.

#### *Edit*

From your comments, I understand that you feel the mouse should (on transition) move to a vertical position, *relatively* equal to the position on the screen it came from. That is exactly the misunderstanding, since windows (and anything else on the desktop) have an *absolute* size and position (in px). Windows can even be spread over two screens. You can not combine those two and have a consistent desktop.

Comment: I didn't specify semantics in my original question because I figured that somebody else has probably figured this out already, with better semantics than I can specify.  What I had in mind was this:  If I move my mouse from halfway down the monitor, it'll appear halfway down the other monitor.  In other words, if I move from 500 pixels down a 1000 pixel monitor to a 2000 pixel monitor, my mouse will appear 1000 pixels down on the larger monitor.  I understand that it may not be desirable, but I think, if it's possible, it's at least worth a try.

Comment: @Jack You would achive that by aligning both monitors *centered*. Drag the left monitor up, exactly to the middle of the right screen. The way from right screen to left would however be cut of at the (upper/lower) ends then.

Comment: I wish that were true.  No, that just makes the "no-mouse-land" smaller at the top, and creates a new one at the bottom.  I have considered this option.

Comment: @Jack That is what I mentioned, you won't get rid of the "no mouse land" (or no tress-passing if you want) when two screens are of unequal vertical resolution. Don't forget *technically*, you stay on the same desktop, weirdly shaped by the unequal resolutions.

Comment: @Jack I've run into this same problem, but the system just isn't set up that way.  The only way to get it to work would be to change screen resolution on your larger screen to something terribly low, so that the edges of the screens are the same size.  

Unity is trying to make the mappings mimic the physical world.  The screens aren't the same size.

I personally just had to figure out which 'dead spot' bugged me less.